# Passing a variable through req.body from middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a middleware defined like

```
app.use('api/', authenticate, bar);
```

Inside the authenticate function, I am attaching a variable in the `req.body` like

```
req.body.user = foo;
```

But when I do a `console.log(req.body.user)` inside bar; I found `undefined.` However if I attach the variable like `req.user = foo` and then inside the `bar` function I do a `console.log(req.user)` it successfully printing `foo`. Is there any reason the variable attached req.body is losing what is attached to it on its way?

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine ...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.use('*', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Middlewarez");
    req.body.user = { name: "John", last: "Smith" }
    next();
}, function(req, res){
    console.log("Handler")
    console.log(req.body);       // => { user: { name: 'John', last: 'Smith' } }
    res.end("Done");
})

app.listen(8080);
```

Perhaps you're not using the body-parser?

Comment: I am not setting up the header `Content-Type` `application/json` because I am passing a multi-part form data.

Comment: Cool. Which body parser are you using for the multipart data?

Comment: `bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
        limit: '10mb'
    })`